# LocalStorage - save name through form - show on other page

Tags: javascript, html

I have one simple html page with a text field that asks for user's name. i want to save what user enter and on another page i want to retrieve that name and say hello + (user's name).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LocalStorage</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <p>Enter your name</p>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the second page is where the data from first page comes (through localStorage).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>secondPage</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggested approach by using `sessionStorage`.

However, you can also use `localStorage` with the same implementation method. The only differences between them is `localStorage` will keep the data even if you close your browser. Which in this case, saving `userName` I think it's better to use `sessionStorage`.

***1.html***

```
<form action="2.html" onsubmit="callme()">
    <p>Enter your name</p>
    <input id="tbName" type="text">
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    function callme(){
        var name = document.getElementById('tbName').value;
        sessionStorage.setItem('userName', name);
    }
</script>
```

***2.html***

```
<h1 id="welcome"> </h1>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('welcome').innerText = "Hello, " + sessionStorage.getItem('userName');
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much. this is exactly what i want. so this is actually an example what i am trying to do. can you also write the syntax how you would do it with localStorage? i tried changing sessionStorage to localStorage but it gives null.

Comment: first page: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>LocalStorage</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="second.html" onsubmit="callme()">
    <p>Store and Retrieve a Value</p>
    <input id="text" type="text">
    <button id="submit">Set</button>
</form>



<script>
    function callme(){
var name = document.getElementById('text').value;
localStorage.setItem('userName', name);
}

</script>
 
</body>
</html>

Comment: @AliRJ Oh.. Glad you got it working. Looks like we have different programming timezone :).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a homework assignment but this should get you started.

It will involve:

1. First storing the data into localStorage
2. Then directing the user over to the second page - most likely through window.location.href.
3. Then pulling the data back out of localStorage to display there.

Here's a jsfiddle to get you started setting and getting data.

https://jsfiddle.net/em92zbod/

The two main functions are:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
window.localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Where "key" is any identifier you want to use for the value.

Comment: i saw your example. i know how to do this. i am trying to get it through two pages. set value on one page and get the value on other one, not on a alert popout. and this is a small section of a big app not a homework assignment.

Comment: I'm glad you found what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Code update

page 1

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", e => {
    const form = e.target;
    const name = document.getElementById('tbName').value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('userName', name);
  })
})
```

```html
<form action="2.html" id="myForm">
  <p>Enter your name</p>
  <input id="tbName" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Page 2

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById('welcome').textContent = `Welcome ${ sessionStorage.getItem('userName') || "stranger"}`;
})
```

```html
<h1 id="welcome"></h1>
```