# Trying to save input from a form field

Tags: local-storage

I want to save a first name field on a form.
I want to retrieve that name on another page.

This is my retrieval code....
`enter code here`
`enter code here`var fname = localStorage.getItem('first_name');
`enter code here`var lname = localStorage.getItem('last_name');
`enter code here`document.write('');
`enter code here`document.write(fname, " ", lname);
`enter code here`

the retrieval works if I hard code the value.
`enter code here`localStorage.setItem('orgname','Bethel Baptist Church' );

If I try to get the value from the input box it will not work.
`enter code here`localStorage.setItem('first_name',first_name).value;
`enter code here`localStorage.setItem('last_name', first_name);

I think my problem is in assigning the
local Storage to read the input field correctly.

Comment: Have you checked this ost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329180/localstorage-save-name-through-form-show-on-other-page

Answer (score 0):

Yes , The problem is I need to run a php file to save the data to my database.
In order to load the name field on another page I need to save that in java script.
for some reason I am unable to do that.  Finding the correct place to have the local storage set command to work is my issue. I can not do it in the php file. and the on submit
seams to mess with the calling of the php file.